# no mpicxx when compiling examples for NVIDIA CUDA 5

Tags: cuda

I installed the driver and toolkit for CUDA 5 in 64-bit RHEL 6.3 successfully.

However, when I tried compiling the CUDA 5 examples, I got the error message:

> make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples/0_Simple/cppIntegration'
>
> which: no mpicxx

How can I fix this for the CUDA 5 examples to compile?

Answer (score 1):

In order to build the simpleMPI example, you need [some kind of MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) installed on your system.  You can get around this and build most of the samples by doing:

```
 make -k
```

this will attempt to go past errors in the make process and build all targets that can be built.

If you prefer, you can delete this directory:

```
/root/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples/0_Simple/simpleMPI
```

perhaps with the following command, as root:

```
rm -Rf /root/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0_Samples/0_Simple/simpleMPI
```

and relaunch your make.  Personally I think the make -k option is simpler.

(the message about cppIntegration is just the last target that got successfully built)

Comment: How can I install the MPI in order to be able to compile the example that failed compilation?

Comment: Do you know which MPI libraries I have to install in 64-bit RHEL 6.3 for the compilation of all examples to complete successfully?

Comment: as root, try:  yum list mpich2   if it shows as being available, then do yum install mpich2    that should do it  you may also need to do: yum install mpich2-devel

Comment: I did yum install mpich2 , which worked, but mpich2-devel was not available. However, when I now do "which mpich2" I am getting a message that it cannot be found, and so the compilation for that example still does not work. What shall I do next? Thank you so much!

Comment: which mpich2 isn't right.  You have to do which mpicxx  anyway you need mpich2-devel   what happens when you do yum list mpich2-devel ?

Comment: yum list mpich2-devel gives: Error: no matching packages to list. So, how can I install it? Thank you so much!

Comment: I have CentOS 6.2 and I see those packages as available.  Hmm.  What do you get if you do yum list openmpi-devel   ?

Comment: yum list openmpi-devel gives that it is available, and I installed it after also installing openmpi. However, which mpicxx still says not available. Shall shall I do next?

Comment: openmpi installs to a different location on your system than mpich2 does, and you will need to add it's directory to your path.  Look for the mpicxx in something like /usr/mpi/gcc/... (you will have to find it)  Once you've found it, you'll need to update your $PATH environment variable to include the location of mpicxx.   If you're not familiar with MPI you probably have no plans to use it, and this is kind of a waste of time.  Why not just build the cuda samples that don't need it?